JOLT transformation to generate array
I'm working on a JOLT transformation but haven't been very successful so far. I have this input:
{
  "primaryID": "DNI",
  "DNI": 123,
  "CUIL": 345
}

where the primaryID is dynamic, and I could also have different IDs. Instead of having DNI and CUIL, I could have many different labels. With that input, I'd need the following output:
{
  "NationalIds": [
    {
      "Type": "CUIL",
      "Number": 345
    },
    {
      "Type": "DNI",
      "isPrimary": "true",
      "Number": 123
    }
  ]
}

I've been working on this JOLT transformation:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "primaryID": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "CUIL": "NationalIds.CUIL",
      "DNI": "NationalIds.DNI"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "NationalIds": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,Country)": "NationalIds[#2].Country",
          "$": "NationalIds[#2].Type",
          "@": "NationalIds[#2].Number"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "NationalIds": {
        "*": {
          "Type": "NationalIds[&1].Type",
          "Number": {
            "*": {
              "primaryID": {
                "#true": "NationalIds[&4].isPrimary"
              },
              "*": {
                "$": "NationalIds[&4].Number"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

But the output that I get is:
{
  "NationalIds": [
    {
      "Type": "CUIL"
    },
    {
      "Type": "DNI",
      "isPrimary": "true",
      "Number": "123"
    }
  ]
}

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

You can use the following transformation spec
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "NationalIds.&1.Type",
        "@": "NationalIds.&1.Number"
      },
      "primaryID": {
        "*": {
          "@2,&": "NationalIds.&.isPrimary"//put in the common object(s) whenever primaryID's value matches with any of the keys
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "isPrimary?": "True"//check if the attribute exists by ? 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//get rid of the inner keys while keeping outermost key
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&1[]"
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

